# Bootstrap V4 alpha 6 bower install

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tether

I am creating a new project with bootstrap v4 with bower

```
bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.6
```

and these two files are missing

1. bootstrap.min.js in boostrap package
2. tether.min.js in tether package.

But if i use npm i am getting all files

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

Any specific reason or should i include any other plugin for compiling with bower.

Also how can i download only dist. I dont want sass and other files as i am going to directly map it .. Its a small project.

Answer (score 0):

Try again installing bootstrap v4 using bower as I was able to get all the  files in the folder including the above missing files mentioned by you.

Write the following command :

$  bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.6

You can delete SASS and other files manually after you link the required files in your index.